# Starry Knight, or Crazy Heights

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

> Apple Bounce Chip Desk Egg Fizzle Gird Heat Image Jewel Kangaroo Liquor Mustache Nickel Opportunity Person Quiz Reel Saturate Tornado Umbrella Vehicle Wallaby Xylophone  Yak Zebra

---

> Alabaster Birth Colonel Disgust Elephant Farm Grip Heifer Igloo Juice King Lemon Marathon Nocturnal Orange Piece Quip Roust Surgeon Tough Upper Veracity Watermelon Xylol Yellow Zenith

---

```
        | Bear | Frog | Lion | Deer | Crab
--------+------+------+------+------+------
Maple   |  uv  |  mu  |  ud  |  ju  |  qu
--------+------+------+------+------+------
Oak     |  if  |  hi  |  yi  |  wi  |  ki
--------+------+------+------+------+------
Hickory |  re  |  se  |  te  |  le  |  ne
--------+------+------+------+------+------
Birch   |  la  |  ar  |  at  |  ga  |  ba
--------+------+------+------+------+------
Pine    |  no  |  op  |  zo  |  ox  |  co
```

---

---

---

```
Red   \                Orange\
       |--------> af          |--------> di
1.12.5/                2.25.2/

Yellow\                Green \
       |--------> tu          |--------> ul
1.24.5/                2.13.3/

Blue  \                Indigo\
       |--------> ti          |--------> ec
2.1.4 /                2.17.1/

Violet\
       |--------> am
1.6.3 /
```

---

---

---

> Professor Electrician Farmer Clerk Saint

+

> Lane Street Avenue Drive Road

**Hint #1**

> The title provides an important clue to solving the first part if the puzzle.

**Hint #2**

> _ _ + _ _ + _ _

Comment: This is certainly an excellent puzzle! All I have are a few observations, probably not even enough to be worth posting as a partial answer, but I'm following to see what people come up with!

Comment: @Somebody thank you for the kind comment!

Comment: Uhh, there's no word for L in the first list. Is this on purpose?

Comment: is it possible that fixing that error changes the puzzle?

Comment: Is there also a specific reason why "Y" isn't in the list?

Comment: perhaps another hint? Pretty please?

Comment: @cmxu fortunately the error does not affect the final answer.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking along a certain lime and it made a lot of sense but the new word changed that, guess ill try something else.

Comment: @North hmmmmm.....how about tomorrow?

Comment: @cmxu what was the line? I want to make sure I'm not being deceptive.

Comment: Yeah ever since you added L and Ys, nothing has made sense. MAPLE would've kinda made sense if you got to it by removing the latter half of the word (MUST(-ACHE), PER(-SON), APP(-LE) E(-GG?), but LLA isn't a word, no matter how much you stretch it.

Comment: I deleted my comment above because it seems like kinda a spoiler, I'll add it in a spoiler tag in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Added some more thoughts and progress to my post if anyone is interested. This puzzle is really keeping me up, but I'm gonna sleep now.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think I got the first part, but I'm completely stuck after that. Hoping someone can help me finish it.

Edit: I've added a bit more progress/thoughts.

Edit 2: Credit to JS1 for the ending and his thoughts in the comments.

First Part.

> Starry [k]Night, or Crazy [h]Eights is a clue to look for words that are still words without the first letter. In the first list, you get ([B]ounce, [I]mage, [R]eel, [C]hip, [H]eat) = `Birch`. The second list gets you ([F]arm, [R]oust, [O]range, [G]rip) = `Frog`. `Birch` and `Frog` both appear in the grid and hint at `ar`.

Second Part.

> While we know what the colors are, the numbers are not immediately obvious. However, one can observe that the numbers come in a triple $(a,b,c)$. We notice that $a \in[1,2]$, $b \in [1,...,25]$, and $c \in [1,...,6]$. After quite a bit of trial and error with other possibilities, this actually reminds of the first two lists of words. $a$ refers to either the first or second list, thus 1 or 2. $b$ refers to which word in the list, there are 26 (although not at the start haha). $c$ refers to the letter number in that word. So we get the following$$1.12.6 = R, 2.25.2 = E, 1.24.5 = P, 2.13.3 = R, 2.1.4 = B, 2.17.1 = Q, 1.6.3 = Z$$ From this, and hints from the comments, and a bit of working backwards, JS1 deduces that since $2.1.4 = B$ which is the same as [B]lue, we get `ti` (not sure what to do about [R]ed).

Third Part.

> Credit to JS1. Street = St = Saint. Therefore, we get `st`.

Final Answer.

> Adding all three parts we get $$ar + ti + st = artist$$

Random Thoughts/Clues.

> So here I'm just gonna put a random collection of other thoughts/clues. First, we know that in the original statement of the puzzle this was still solvable even though there was no L word in the first list and no Y words in either list. We also know that the above is likely correct because of what the author has mentioned. From the comments we also can assume that in the end only one of the Color/Number to letter things out of the seven will be used. We also know that in all likelihood since the author said that it didn't matter this will not involve (1.12.6 or 1.24.5). 1.25.2 the word changed from zebra to yellow but the letter is still E. Now onto other ideas. We know that in the end we will be summing in some way these two lists. My original thought was that there are two categories again and so we will do a pairwise summing and get 5 2-letter combos for a 10-letter solution. However, now I think that the item to letter isn't really a function but just sort of arbitrary. There are two theories on `ar`. One, it affects or hints at something in the next diagram. Two, it is distinct and together with the next diagram you will get two 2-letter things that will hint at the final puzzle. My only real thoughts on `ar` are that it could be Argon = Gas when excited is `Violet`, `ar` is a sounding of the letter `r`, `ar` hints at a shift cipher of 17 from a to r, `ar` is actually `a` and `r` distinctly that hint at something. No clue, probably none of those are correct. Finally, just thoughts on what the third diagrams could mean. My best theory is that they could be just a pair of letters to be used with the above pair. Also thinking they could imply some sort of substitution from say `E` -> `DI`. No clue. 'ar' + 'di' = 'raid?' 'arid?', 'ar' + ec' = 'care?'

Comment: You're on the right track! congrats.

Comment: For the last part, I noticed rot13(Qbpgbe = Qe = Qevir, Fgerrg = Fg = Fnvag), but I'm not sure how that fits with the rest of the puzzle.

Comment: @JS1 you're correct, and one of those is important, and one wasn't supposed to be there. Yet another mistake on my part. I should really proofread these things in more depth.

Comment: Rot13(Fvapr gur ynfg cneg nccrnef gb or "fg" onfrq ba gur ynfg rqvg, V fhfcrpg gur nafjre gb or "negvfg".  Jbexvat onpxjneqf, gur frpbaq cneg zhfg or "gv", naq gur ernfba zvtug or gung 2.1.4 -> "o" juvpu zngpurf gur svefg yrggre bs "oyhr".  Nygubhtu erq jbexf gbb sbe gung ernfba, ohg gur erq jbeq jnf punatrq gjvpr nyernql.)

Comment: Hint added. @North

Comment: @JS1 I added your thoughts to the solution above, some of it seems a bit tenuous so (i.e connection between rot13(O naq Oyhr)), and I don't really understand the rot13(Fgerrg fg Fnvag) thing, but it seems to make sense for the final answer given the hint. I'll keep thinking about it until it gets confirmed or denied

Comment: Rot13(Fg vf gur nooerivngvba sbe obgu fgerrg naq fnvag).  I'm not sure about the color part.  I think your explanation of the numbers was correct though.

Comment: Nice! You solved it! I'm going to wait to award the bounty so this question can get more attention

Comment: It's nice to know I was on the right track! I actually had all of the 2nd part, just couldn't figure out the first part. excellent solve!